# Javascript passing null to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Javascript code passing an object modeled exactly the same as my C# object 
`CreateItemModel`. However, problem is in my Controller code a property that was set in javascript as `new String();` gets deserialized to C# as `null`.

Javascript Code

```
$('[step="4"]').click(function () {
    //shortened for brevety
    var _model = new Object();
    _model.ItemDesc = new String();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'CreateItem',
        data: _model,
        success: function (msg) {

            status = JSON.stringify(msg);
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {

            status = JSON.stringify(msg);
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

C# Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CreateItemCallAsync(CreateItemModel item)
{
   //breakpoint here 
   var test = item.ItemDesc; //the property is null here
}
```

I was expecting a `string.empty` value here but I am getting a `null` value instead. I tried setting the `_model.ItemDesc` to `''` `""` `new String()` in my Javascript code. But always getting a `null` value.

**Questions:**

1. Why is this behavior occurring?
2. How to get my expected value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` will interpret empty strings as `null`. You can use the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property of `DisplayFormatAttribute` to have the property bind as an empty string.

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the name `item` to `_model`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CreateItemCallAsync(CreateItemModel _model)
    {
       //breakpoint here 
       var test = _model.ItemDesc; //the property is null here
    }
```

Also Add `contentType` and `dataType` properties to your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
```